# Include AFnetworking linker errors

Tags: ios, afnetworking, linker-errors

Could anyone tell me what's going on?

I get 9 errors after including AFnetworking, see below.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2nd7LiU.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/YEyt1zi.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to include the Security framework in your project.

Comment: When I add the Security framework I'll get the same errors + another: ignoring file /Users/Daan/Documents/IOS-apps/Testapp4/Security.framework/Security, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/Daan/Documents/IOS-apps/Testapp4/Security.framework/Security (2 slices)

Comment: It looks like maybe you copied the framework into your project folder?

Comment: Now I have successfully added the framework, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and was seeing about 15 mach -0 linker compiler error messages. Adding the security framework reduced that # to 7 errors.

Did some more research and found that you might also need to add the **SystemConfiguration.framework** via xCode.

This completely resolved the issue for me.

As an FYI - I was using xCode 5, targeting iOS 7 and using AFNetworking version 2.0.

Adding as an answer, in case other people find that simply adding security.framework doesnt resolve things for them.

Thanks to Firoze above for the accepted answer.